# Separating months and years sharing the same column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I currently have a 'Date' column serving as my index for a pandas dataframe that is of the form:

```
January
February
....
Year2 
January
February
...
Year3
```

(It came from a pdf table extractor.) Is there anyway easily to separate the years and months out, with each month having the proper year or have a proper date-time column to serve as my index?

Right now I am thinking of applying a function where I select if a value is numeric and if so clone over to another column and delete, but there should be an easier way.

All are objects, but the years are in numeric form, whereas the months are in long string form.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Share the dataset so that people can help you properly

Answer (score 1):

Using `ffill` with `to_numeric`

```
df['Year']=pd.to_numeric(df.MixCol,errors='coerce').ffill().astype(int)
df=df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.MixCol,errors='coerce').isnull()]
df
Out[86]: 
     MixCol  Year
1   January  2017
2  February  2017
4   January  2018
5  February  2018
```

---

Data input

```
MixCol
2017
January
February
2018
January
February
2019
```